# LL(1) parser conflict when parsing C language BNF

Tags: parsing, ll-grammar

I'v calculated all the first sets of each production according to https://cs.wmich.edu/~gupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm, but I found the first sets is highly conflicted.

For example, code like this:

```
static int test () {}
|
```

the input token is static, but I don't know if this is a `function-definition` or `declaration` (because both production's first sets has the token static/int/identifier) until my cursor reach to the `{` token.

So is there any way I can choose a right production without drawback?

Comment: Why limit yourself to LL(1)? That will surely force you to use a more complicated grammar, to the extent that it is even possible. Having said that, in the particular case of function definition/declaration, you really only need to left factor (and, of course, fix up the AST later on).

Comment: @rici so what algorithm is better in this situation? LR(0)? LALR?

Comment: LALR(1) parser generators are readily available for many implementation languages and the grammar is mostly straightforward. GLR and other fully general algorithms are also available in several implementation languages.

Comment: @rici I'm trying to handcraft a c language parser for practicing, do you suggest that using LALR(1) or GLR is better than LL(1)? Cause I'v thinking to use LALR(1), and I still don't know how to solve the problem I asked even use LALR(1). Even with https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html

Comment: That grammar is LALR(1), although it's an old version of C. It's not LL. With bottom-up parsing, there is no problem to solve, because it is not necessary to figure out which production is to be used until the end of the production is reached.